# Have Stack Overflow automatically suggest tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-autocomplete, automation

Why doesn't Stack Overflow automatically suggest tags?  Stack Overflow can already find questions similar to mine.  If most of those similar questions have the same tags, why not put automatically fill in the tags field? Or at least provide buttons for a few obvious tags?

Comment: Could help newbies quite a bit, they are often very bad at tagging (can't really blame them, the tag system can be kind of a mess).

Comment: I'd be all for it, as long as the system didn't suggest tags that we are working desperately to get rid of.

Comment: @Tim: It should only suggest from the most popular tags I would assume. Te system could guess based primarily on any code block content, right? I can see some strange suggestions based on body text if it were just a free-for-all from the whole grab-bag of existing tags.

Comment: @TimPost: If there's a way to indicate that a tag is deprecated, easy.  In fact, suggestions would probably reduce the number of deprecated tags used and increase tag homogeneity.  (The latter might be a drawback.)

Comment: @WesleyMurch It's happened before (especially on other sites) that the most popular tags were also the most inappropriate, although when that happens automated tagging is the least of the site's problems.

Comment: This would probably serve to worsen the problem of users throwing in as many tags as they can think of just to fill up the maximum of 5 per question, unless there's a way to throttle the system from suggesting too many tags.