# Suggesting tags based on question body and title is fluffing sweet. Can we have this on SO?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

I just asked a question over on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com), and when I got to the tag selection stage, I found a little dollop of UX goodness waiting for me:

[image]

The system seems to have picked out likely keywords from my post and is helping me, a new user of the site, correctly categorize my question. Clicking on any of these adds it to the tag field, also a nice touch.

The same feature does not seem to be present on Stack Overflow (tested both with my real account and a dummy new account created for this purpose):

[image]

Interestingly, this has been requested quite a while ago and declined: [Automatic tag suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/auto-tagging) (also [When asking a question, could the page suggest relevant tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85206/when-asking-a-question-could-the-page-suggest-relevant-tags) and [Have Stack Overflow automatically suggest tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132681/have-stack-overflow-automatically-suggest-tags)) but it's apparently now been implemented.

This seems like a great thing to have for new users (and I see it's even here on Meta!); can it be added to Stack Overflow?

Comment: It's here on Meta as well; I'm sure it'll come to SO too.

Comment: Yes, I saw it when I posted this. Any idea how new it is, @MartijnPieters?

Comment: It wasn't there on February 1st (when posted a MSO question before), it is there today. I suspect it was added today, after the datacenter switchover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been turned on for Stack Overflow for...a while.